# Trying to repair Ubuntu install - No EFI system partition was found even though I am in GPT/UEFI

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I am trying to repair an Ubuntu install that started to boot into a blank screen after trying (and failing) to boot from a live Manjaro USB. The Ubuntu live USB loads up fine, but when I tried to reinstall Ubuntu from the live session, it tells me that no EFI system partition was found and that my system may not be able to boot.

`sudo parted -l` says otherwise, though:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA SPCC Solid State (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 512GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  524MB  523MB   ntfs         Basic data partition          hidden, diag
 2      524MB   629MB  105MB   fat32        EFI system partition          boot, esp
 3      629MB   646MB  16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 4      646MB   255GB  254GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 5      255GB   256GB  618MB   ntfs                                       hidden, diag
 6      256GB   512GB  257GB   ext4         GManUbu19


Model: ATA ST1000LM035-1RK1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      17.4kB  134MB   134MB                Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 2      135MB   1000GB  1000GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata


Model: Flash USB Disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 7940MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  7940MB  7939MB  fat32        Microsoft Basic Data  msftdata


ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls /sys/firmware/efi
config_table  esrt              fw_vendor  runtime-map  vars
efivars       fw_platform_size  runtime    systab
```

Is there any way to reinstall Ubuntu without wiping the EFI partition? I feel like that's going to give me a very bad time.

Comment: I had Ubuntu and Windows 10; though I finally got my live USB of Manjaro to work so I decided to switch to that instead; thought I’d leave the question open for people to leave answers in case anyone else has A similar issue

Comment: [this Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing) may be of help to you.